# How to change colors in headers column using xlsx - npm upon export

Tags: reactjs, excel, npm, background-color, xlsx

I'am new in react, and I have this project where I'm exporting the data inside my datatable into an excel file.

I've already done my searches and now I've come here with hoping for your guidance.

For this project i have used the xlsx - npm

imports

```
// Import XLSX library
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
// Import saveAs function from file-saver library
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';
```

code for exporting

```
    const exportToExcel = async () => {
        try {

            const workbook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
            const worksheetData = [];
    
            // Add headers to worksheetData
            const headers = columns.map(column => column.label);
            worksheetData.push(headers);

            const calculateMaxLength = (value) => {
                return String(value).length;
            };
            
            const columnWidths = {
               
                branch: 10,
                transaction_id: 15,
                trx_date: 10,
                item: 15,
                item_description: 80,
                misc_transaction_number: 25,
                referrence: 80,
                transaction_type: 20,
                primary_quantity: 15,
                oum: 10,
                unit_cost: 10, 
                charge_to: 20,
                transaction_value:20,
                account_code:20,
                account_description: 30,
                ['Current 1-7 Bus. Days']: 20,
                ['8-14 Bus. Days']: 20,
                ['15-21 Bus. Days']: 20,
                ['22-30 Bus. Days']: 20,
                ['Over 30 Bus. Days']: 20,
                charge_to:20,
                accounting_remarks:20,
                sot_support_remarks:20,
                dc_docs_remarks:20,
                logistic_remarks:20,
                engineering_remarks:20,
                procurement_remarks:20,
                acctg_reports_remarks:20,
                hr_remarks:20,
            };
            

            data.forEach(row => {
                const rowData = columns.map((column) => {
                    const dataKey = column.dataKey;
                    let value;
            
                    if (dataKey === "charge_to") {
                        // Apply your custom logic for the "charge_to" column
                        value = (row[dataKey] || row["CHARGE TO"] || "").trim();
                    } else if (dataKey === "unit_cost") {
                        // Format the "Unit Cost" value to two decimal places
                        value = (row[dataKey] != null ? parseFloat(row[dataKey]).toFixed(2) : "").trim();
                    } 
                    else if (dataKey === "trx_date") {
                        // Format the "trx_date" as a custom date format (d-mmm-yy)
                        const date = new Date(row[dataKey]);
                        value = { t: 'd', v: date, z: 'd-mmm-yy' }; // Set custom date format
                    
                    } else if (dataKey === "Current 1-7 Bus. Days" ||
                        dataKey === "8-14 Bus. Days" ||
                        dataKey === "15-21 Bus. Days" ||
                        dataKey === "22-30 Bus. Days" ||
                        dataKey === "Over 30 Bus. Days") 
                        
                        {
            
                        if (aging <= 7) {
                            value = dataKey === "Current 1-7 Bus. Days" ? row["transaction_value"] || "" : "";
                        } else if (aging > 7 && aging <= 14) {
                            value = dataKey === "8-14 Bus. Days" ? row["transaction_value"] || "" : "";
                        } else if (aging > 14 && aging <= 21) {
                            value = dataKey === "15-21 Bus. Days" ? row["transaction_value"] || "" : "";
                        } else if (aging > 21 && aging <= 30) {
                            value = dataKey === "22-30 Bus. Days" ? row["transaction_value"] || "" : "";
                        } else {
                            value = dataKey === "Over 30 Bus. Days" ? row["transaction_value"] || "" : "";
                        }
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        // For other columns, use the default logic
                        value = row[dataKey] !== undefined ? row[dataKey] : '';
                    }
            
                    // Calculate the maximum length considering both headers and data
                    const maxLength = Math.max(calculateMaxLength(value), calculateMaxLength(column.label));
            
                    return value;
               
                });
            
                worksheetData.push(rowData);
            });

    
            // Create worksheet from worksheetData
            const ws = XLSX.utils.aoa_to_sheet(worksheetData);

            ws['!cols'] = columns.map(column => ({ width: columnWidths[column.dataKey] || 10 })); // Default width is 10

            XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(workbook, ws, 'chambahi');
    
            // Convert workbook to array buffer
            const arrayBuffer = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
    
            // Create a Blob from array buffer
            const blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8' });
    
            // Save the Blob as a file
            saveAs(blob, 'example.xlsx');

             } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error exporting data to Excel:', error);
        }

    };
```

i did some styling but it doesn't seems to work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.